# .NET Binary XML

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

How does .NET's Binary XML work?

There's some documentation on it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219210.aspx, but it doesn't say how to make it. There isn't even an example of the output. I'm guessing anything related to binary xml would be in System.Xml, but I can't find anything.

Also, my searches for binary xml have led me to [XmlDictionaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366446.aspx), which apparently can write "binary XML format", but it doesn't even exist in System.Xml!

My goal is to possibly serialize my data in binary xml (right now I'm using XmlSerializer, which writes standard, human-readable xml).

Can anyone give me an example of how to serialize to binary xml or even just write binary xml?

Comment: out of curiosity; what is the *purpose* of your choosing binary xml? I just want to check other options might not be more suitable...

Comment: wha version of .NET are you using?  XmlDictionaryWriter is in System.Xml for .NET 3.0 upwards according to that link, not sure why you say it doesn't exist?

Comment: @MarcGravell - I was realling just looking into this out of curiosity. I was just wondering what .NET's binary xml looks like and how effective it is performance wise. I'll post my results to Dave81's answer.

Comment: My point being - if final size and CPU are your concern, you might instead want to look at things like protobuf-net, which tends to trump both.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Hmm... I took a look at it, but I don't want to include any unnecessary third-party dll's if I don't have to. Standard XML works fine for what I'm doing, but thanks for the tip anyways; I might use it for a future project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XmlDictionaryWriter is in System.Runtime.Serialization which you need to add as a reference first.